# Getting 404 in Jmeter while on one machine while on other machine runs fine

Tags: jmeter

I'm running JMeter 3.0 on a laptop (Lenovo y700) with win10. I'm trying to get a response from a website and getting a 404 response. when I try other web sites everything works fine. tried running it from my desktop PC (win 8.1) but got the same 404 , and with another website, everything runs fine. now here's the tricky part. I've tried it again on a mac laptop (not sure the version of the os) and there everything was running fine (including the website who didn't work on the other machines).
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xu4r.jpg)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNwxN.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try using SOAP/XML-RPC Request with Send SOAPAction enabled and one HTTP Header Manager in the request.

[Apache Jmeter - Samplers - SOAP/XML-RPC_Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#SOAP/XML-RPC_Request)

Answer (score 0):

Look at your website logs.  It is unfortunately common for developers to leave a reference on a web page which is not built out, leaving an orphaned reference.  if you see the 404 in the HTTP request logs and in your results then you can be objectively certain that the reference is missing.

- Should have been caught by development but was not
- Should have been caught by functional testing but was not
- Test blamed for being faulty because it reported something no one else caught

Common scenario....